# Which Inspector General oversees CFIUS?

Tags: united-states, foreign-direct-investment

The Committee on Foreign Investment in the United States (CFIUS) is an interagency panel in the US government which reviews the national security implications of foreign investment in the United States.  It has the power to reject deals which it concludes would lead to adverse national security consequences.

Now each cabinet department of the US Government has an Inspector General, an officer who conducts independent investigations of waste, fraud, abuse, and misconduct within that department.  But CFIUS is not part of any cabinet department, instead it consists of representatives from a bunch of different cabinet departments.  So my question is, which Inspector General oversees CFIUS, particularly the CFIUS approval process?  Who would investigate allegations that a CFIUS decision was influenced by improper motives, for instance?

Answer (score 1):

[CFIUS](https://home.treasury.gov/policy-issues/international/the-committee-on-foreign-investment-in-the-united-states-cfius) is constituted within the Treasury Department. And so the relevant [Inspector General](https://www.treasury.gov/about/organizational-structure/ig/Pages/default.aspx) (acting) would be Richard K. Delmar, following the retirement last year of Eric M. Thorson